# Read Extended Linear Address Records in Hex (Intel) C

Tags: c, file, hex, intel, checksum

I've got three Intel hexadecimal lines which look like that :

```
:02 0000 04 FFFF                   FC   // 04 means Extended Linear Address Record
:0B 0010 00 6164647265737320676170 A7  // 00 means Data
:00 0000 01                        FF // 01 means EOF
```

I added blank spaces intentionally to make it more readable, but it is normally in a single piece. Examples and explanations taken from [Intel HEX Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX).

My purpose is to write a function which extracts the data part being, in this example, `6164647265737320676170`.

So far I imagine it like that; first *two characters*, **data's size**, would be used like this :

```
int getSize(char* intelHex)
{
    return intelHex[1]*16 + intelHex[2]; // Skip colon and compute only data's size
}
```

In my case the **physical adress** part on *four characters*, which on second line is `0010` is already known so I ignore it. The part specifying **type** on *two characters* shall always be `04`, `00` then `01`, so i'll check that like that :

```
getline(file, hexLine); // Fill hexLine with first line    

if (hexLine[7] != '0' ||hexLine[8] != '4') // First line need "04" as type
    puts("Error, Extended Linear Address Record type is expected.\n"); // 
else {
    // Process first line 
}

getline(file, hexLine); // Fill hexLine with second line  

if (hexLine[7] != '0' || hexLine[8] != '0') // Second line need "00" as type
    puts("Error, Data type is expected.\n");
else {  

    // Process second line, extract data
    // for example 

   int size = getSize(hexLine);
   char data[size];
   for (int i = 9; i < 9 + size; i++)
       data[i - 9] = hexLine[i]; // Each data part's hexadecimal number is stored
}

getline(file, hexLine);   // Fill hexLine with third and last line

if (strcmp(hexLine, ":00000001FF") != 0) // EOF is always the same so we check the whole line instead of just the type
    puts("Error, EOF type is expected.\n");
```

What I don't understand and can't imagine how to compute is the first line's **data part**, here `FFFF` and how to check the **CheckSum part**, which are the *last two characters*.

Quote from [ARM Information Center Hex File Format](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka9903.html) :

> Extended linear address records are also known as 32-bit address records and HEX386 records. These records contain the upper 16 bits (bits 16-31) of the data address. The extended linear address record always has two data bytes.

In my particular case, this part is equal to `1FFF` although second line's data part contains entirely the data I wish to extract. What does it mean then ? Or should I just ignore it ?

As for the checksum, quoting Intel HEX Wikipedia page again :

> For example, in the case of the record :0300300002337A1E, the sum of the decoded byte values is 03 + 00 + 30 + 00 + 02 + 33 + 7A = E2. The two's complement of E2 is 1E, which is the checksum byte appearing at the end of the record.

I guess I need a function to find `1E` from `E2`, but I have no idea how to write it.

Any hint, new piece of information or possible explanation regarding these parts, especially how to process them, would be a blessing. I'd be glad to explain myself more further if anything is confusing.

Comment: I suggest to step back and write a function that that parses a string  into a `struct { uint8_t len; uint16_t addr, uint8_t type, uint8_t data[255]; uint8_t check; }` and returns 0: success else error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a struct like this :

```
struct HexIntel {

    size_t m_len;
    unsigned char m_addr[8];
    unsigned char m_data[255];
    unsigned char m_checkSum;
    bool m_endOfFile;
    bool m_success; // Only set true after checking the EOF, the checksums etc.
};
```

Two very useful enum to avoid magic numbers :

**One for the types**

```
enum HEX_INTEL_TYPE {
    DATA = 0, HEX_EOF = 1, EXTENDED_SEGMENT_ADDRESS = 2, START_SEGMENT_ADDRESS = 3,
    EXTENDED_LINEAR_ADDRESS = 4, START_LINEAR_ADDRESS = 5
}; // In fact initializing those values is useless since the default values are the same
```

And one to name each value of the tab :

```
enum HEX_INTEL_RECORD {
    LEN_MSB = 0, LEN_LSB = 1, ADDR_MSB = 2, ADDR_MSB2 = 3, ADDR_LSB2 = 4, ADDR_LSB = 5,
    TYPE_MSB = 6, TYPE_LSB = 7, DATA_START = 8
};
```

And after parsing each line into a tab of int with the following function :

```
unsigned char hexCharToInt(char c)
{
    const unsigned char ERROR = 16;
    const int asciiNumberBetweenDigitAndAlpha = 7; // In ASCII, 7 ponctuations marks separate digits from uppercase alphabetical character
    if (c > '/' && c < ':') // In ASCII, '0' is after '/' and ':' after '9'
        return c - '0'; // In ASCII '0' = 48; '1' = 49..
    else if (c > '@' && c < 'G') // In ASCII, 'A' is after '@'
        return c - '0' - asciiNumberBetweenDigitAndAlpha;
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not hexadecimal character, can't be parsed into a int.\n");
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

I just initialized the struct depending on the type of line I was reading.

The function to check the checksum of a line is the following :

```
bool checkSum(const int* hexTab, const size_t sizeOfTab)
{
    unsigned char checkSum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < sizeOfTab - 2; i += 2) // Byte by byte until checksum
    {
        unsigned char currentByteValue = hexTab[i] * 16 + hexTab[i + 1];
        if (currentByteValue + checkSum < 256)
            checkSum += currentByteValue;
        else
        {
            while (currentByteValue != 0)
            {
                if (checkSum == 255)
                    checkSum = 0;
                else
                    checkSum++;
                currentByteValue--;
            }
        }
    }

    const unsigned char twoComplement = 256 - checkSum;
    const unsigned char tabCheckSum = hexTab[sizeOfTab - 2] * 16 + hexTab[sizeOfTab - 1];

    if (twoComplement == tabCheckSum)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

I didn't intend to share this at the first place but thought it could help. Not the full solution, but the main functions which helped structuring the solution. If any improvement can be added don't hesitate to share them.